# Matching a list of sentences to another list with python

Tags: python-2.7

I have 2 lists as shown below. Basically I want to match the items in `list1` with `list2` which ignores everything before and after the sentence in `list2`.

For example element in `list1` "**Jill is a very good girl**" matches with `list2` "She comes first because **Jill is a very good girl**", I want to ignore "She comes first because". So if `list1` in `list2`, it means `True` else `False`.

```
list1 = [
"Jill is a very good girl",
"John is a very good boy"]
```

The second list as shown below:

```
list2 = [
"John is a very good boy but he is naughty",
"John is a very good boy but he doesn't sleep",
"He eats a lot but John is a very good boy",
"Every girl is naughty but Jill is a very good girl",
"She comes first because Jill is a very good girl"]
```

Comment: hey what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried a simple match with list1 with list2. My problem is the other strings which is creating a problem with my match phase. It means I just cannot do a simple match like for i in list1, if list1 in list2, print "True" else print "False". I hope you got the idea.

Comment: I don't get the idea. Me, I'd like to see your code. Perhaps we can pin-point where you went off.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following logic:-

```
def special_list_in(list1, list2):
    flag = True
    for sentList1 in list1:
        temp_flag = False;
        for sentList2 in list2:
            if sentList1.lower() in sentList2.lower():
                temp_flag = True;
                break;
        flag = flag and temp_flag
    return flag

special_list_in(list1, list2)
```

If you require string matching should be case sensitive, then please remove `.lower()`.

Comment: @fear_matrix, can you check if this solves your question?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this piece of code:

```py
list1 = ["B",
         "A"]

list2 = ["ABC",
         "AB",
         "AA",
         "CCA",
         "BA"]

def check_matching(list_1, list_2):
    for sentence_2 in list_2:
        result = []
        for sentence_1 in list_1:
            if sentence_1 in sentence_2:
                result.append(True)
                break
        if not result:
            return False
    return True


print check_matching(list1,list2)
```

Notice that if you remove the `A` from `CCA` (4th element of `list2`) it starts to return `False`. You can test this function with your strings in lists.